# atcoder アルゴリズムと数学　演習問題集　029 - Climb Stairs

Tags: c++

atcoder  アルゴリズムと数学　演習問題集　029 - Climb Stairs の質問です。
https://atcoder.jp/contests/math-and-algorithm/tasks/math_and_algorithm_ab
1から45まですべての結果が模範解答と一致しているはずなのですがなぜかうまくいきません。
下記のコードでwaになる理由を教えてください。

**問題文**
太郎君はN 段の階段を上ろうとしています。彼は一歩で 1 段か2 段上ることができます。
0 段目から出発し、N 段目にたどり着くまでの移動方法が何通りあるかを計算してください。

**制約**
1≤N≤45
N は整数

**自分の回答**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int st(int N, vector<int>& v){
    if (N == 0) return v[0] =1;
    if (N == 1) return v[1] =1;

    if (v[N] == 0){
        return v[N] = st(N-1, v) + st(N -2, v);
    }else{
        return v[N];
    }
}

int main(){
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector <int> v(N, 0);

    cout << st(N, v) << endl;
}
```

**模範解答**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int N, dp[54];

int main() {
    // 入力
    cin >> N;

    // 動的計画法 → 答えの出力
    for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
        if (i <= 1) dp[i] = 1;
        else dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2];
    }
    cout << dp[N] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ベクトル`v`への範囲外アクセスをしているのが原因です。

```cpp
vector <int> v(N, 0);
```

こちらで確保したベクトルの添字として有効なのは、0～N-1までです。
v[N]にアクセスしようとすると、範囲外アクセスとなり、どのような値が返ってくるか分かりません。
返ってきた値が 0 でない場合、その値がそのまま関数`st`の戻り値となってしまいます。

サイズを1つ増やして、添字0～Nまで使えるようにしましょう。

```cpp
vector <int> v(N+1, 0);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、未定義の処理について勉強になりました。